# Programmatically login user in Spring Security in a Filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, servlet-filters

I am trying to implement a filter to programmatically login a user based on certain criteria.

This is my filter-method:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

    boolean typo3loggedin = true;
    String memberNo = "100003";

    HttpRequestResponseHolder holder = new HttpRequestResponseHolder(request, response);
    SecurityContext securityContext = contextRepository.loadContext(holder);
    Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();


    if (cookies != null && cookies.length > 0 ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            String name = cookies[i].getName();
            String value = cookies[i].getValue();
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("fe_typo_user")) typo3loggedin = true; //
            logger.debug(String.format("cookie-name: %s, cookie-value: %s", name, value));
        }
    }

    if (typo3loggedin && (authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated())) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        if (authentication == null ) authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(memberNo, "", grantedAuths);
        securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
        contextRepository.saveContext(securityContext, request, response);
        logger.debug("Logged-in from typo3 as user " + memberNo);
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
```

But whenever I try to save the Authentication, I get the following error:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mortbay.jetty.Response cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper
            at org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.saveContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:108)
            at com.scaratec.bueroprint.mdb.ui.server.filter.SsoFilter.doFilter(SsoFilter.java:74)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:233)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
            at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
            at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
            at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

The exception message itself doesn't make any sense to me since `org.mortbay.jetty.Response` implements `HttpServletResponse` which is taken as parameter to `saveContext()`.

**UPDATE:** As suggested in the comments below, I have extended the `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` which is made for exactly this scenario. This totally solved my problem.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply extend a `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` instead of rolling your own?

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you!! This actually solved my problem. I wasn't aware of this filter but this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a simple class cast issue. The request object isn't an instance of `SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper`. This class is use to wrap the request as it passes through the Spring Security filter chain - it's created by the `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`.

It looks like the call to the `SecurityContextRepository` originates in a call from your own filter class and the request *hasn't* passed through the security filter chain (looking at the stacktrace, there is no mention of Spring Security filters). Hence the request object is still of the original container type, rather than the wrapper.